# ¿Por qué no funciona mi constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Soy nuevo en java y quisiera saber porque me marca error al compilar, ya que intento que mi opbjeto de tipo cuenta inicialice con los valores que les muestro a continuación

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaCuenta
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Crea un objeto cuenta llamado miCuenta
        Cuenta miCuenta = new Cuenta("juan carlos", 50.00);
        Cuenta cuentita = new Cuenta();

        //muestra el valor inicial del nombre(null)
        System.out.printf("El saldo de %s es: $%.2f%n", miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
        System.out.printf("El saldo de %s es: $%.2f%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());
        //
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        //pide y lee el nombre
        System.out.println("Escribe el montro a depositar para cuenta 1: ");
        double montoDeposito = entrada.nextDouble(); //lee una linea de texto
        miCuenta.depositar(montoDeposito);//Coloca el nombre en miCenta

        System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n", miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
        System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());

        System.out.print("Escriba el monto a depositar para cuenta2: "); // indicador (promt)
        montoDeposito = entrada.nextDouble(); // obtiene entrada del usuario
        System.out.printf("%nsumando %.2f al saldo de cuenta2%n%n", montoDeposito);
        cuentita.depositar(montoDeposito); // suma al saldo de cuenta2

        System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n",miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
        System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());
    }
}
```

---

************* Otra clase*************************

```
public class Cuenta
{
    //variables de instancia
    private String nombre;
    private double saldo;

    //Constructor de la cuenta que sólo recibe dos parametros
    public void Cuenta(String nombre, double saldo)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;

        if(saldo > 0.0) 
        {       
            this.saldo = saldo;
        }
    }




    public void depositar(double montoDeposito)
    {
        if(montoDeposito > 0.0)
            saldo = saldo + montoDeposito;
    }

    public double obtenerSaldo()
    {
        return saldo;
    }

    public String obtenerNombre()
    {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void establecerNombre(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema ? debes contarnos que error tenes

Answer (score 3):

Revisando tu código veo que tienes mal la clase `Cuenta` ya que para declarar un constructor el método no lleva tipo de retorno en tu caso cambiar:

```
public void Cuenta(String nombre, double saldo){}
```

por:

```
public Cuenta(String nombre, double saldo){}
```

Otra observación es que en el método `main` instancias la clase de la siguiente manera:

```
Cuenta cuentita = new Cuenta();
```

Ya que en tu clase `Cuenta` no declaras un constructor sin parámetros esta línea te marcara error, por cual debes de crear una constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
public Cuenta(){}
```

Tu dos clases quedarian de la siguiente manera:

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Crea un objeto cuenta llamado miCuenta
    Cuenta miCuenta = new Cuenta("juan carlos", 50.00);
    Cuenta cuentita = new Cuenta();

    //muestra el valor inicial del nombre(null)
    System.out.printf("El saldo de %s es: $%.2f%n", miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
    System.out.printf("El saldo de %s es: $%.2f%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());
    //
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    //pide y lee el nombre
    System.out.println("Escribe el montro a depositar para cuenta 1: ");
    double montoDeposito = entrada.nextDouble(); //lee una linea de texto
    miCuenta.depositar(montoDeposito);//Coloca el nombre en miCenta

    System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n", miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
    System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());

    System.out.print("Escriba el monto a depositar para cuenta2: "); // indicador (promt)
    montoDeposito = entrada.nextDouble(); // obtiene entrada del usuario
    System.out.printf("%nsumando %.2f al saldo de cuenta2%n%n", montoDeposito);
    cuentita.depositar(montoDeposito); // suma al saldo de cuenta2

    System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n",miCuenta.obtenerNombre(), miCuenta.obtenerSaldo());
    System.out.printf("Saldo de %s: $%.2f%n%n", cuentita.obtenerNombre(), cuentita.obtenerSaldo());
    }
```

**Cuenta:**

```
public class Cuenta {

    //variables de instancia
    private String nombre;
    private double saldo;

    public Cuenta() {

    }

    //Constructor de la cuenta que sólo recibe dos parametros
    public Cuenta(String nombre, double saldo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;

        if (saldo > 0.0) {
            this.saldo = saldo;
        }
    }

    public void depositar(double montoDeposito) {
        if (montoDeposito > 0.0) {
            saldo = saldo + montoDeposito;
        }
    }

    public double obtenerSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public String obtenerNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void establecerNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Para mayor información de [constructores](http://www.mundojava.net/definicion-de-constructores-de-una-clase.html?Pg=java_inicial_4_4_5.html) y [parámetros](https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/java/capitulo-15.html):

Comment: pero al de hecho no me genera error al crear un objeto sin parámetros, solo me sale error cuando le pongo valores inicales en los objetos Centa

Comment: El error te lo marcaba ya que no habia constructor de la clase Cuenta con esos parámetros, tenias un método con esos parámetros pero no era el constructor de la clase. Ya hiciste la prueba con el código que te proporcione?